# ROBOTIC arm for playing chess

Tags: robotic-arm

I wish to build a chess playing robot with robot arm as shown on youtube, can anyone please tell me which robot arm would suit my purpose and whether it can be bought second hand or alternatively anybody willing to sell used chess arm robot? Please help out.

Comment: Can you include which robot arm you are talking about? It would help us warm up to the question faster if we do not have to go to YouTube search for something and try to guess if that is what is being asked about.

Comment: Do you want it to play left handed (like Ziggy)?

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* KANTAK.P.M, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy one here: [RobotShop](http://www.robotshop.com/en/robotic-arms.html)

But an arm can be fun to make!  If you want to build one, there are a lot of sources to read up on.

Here's a general overview

[societyofrobots](http://www.societyofrobots.com/robot_arm_tutorial.shtml)

The 3 general things you need are...

1) to learn forward kinematics -- this will give you a basis to learn the next step

2) to learn inverse kinematics -- this will give you an understanding of the math used in moving your robotic arm

3) to decide on a hardward platform -- stick with the big names, something like Arduino or Raspberry Pi.  You'll find tons of code & community resources online.